# Putting a vector of points through cartToPolar in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a `vector<Point2f>` with points that I need to convert to polar. The only function I see to do this is `cartToPolar()`, which, for some reason, doesn't allow just a vector of points but instead requires two, each containing only x coordinates and y coordinates respectively.

Is there any graceful solution to this or do I have to manually make these other two vectors?

Comment: you could create a Mat from your vector: `cv::Mat tmp = cv::Mat(yourVectorOfPoints);` then split the channels of the Mat: `std::vector<cv::Mat> split; cv::split(testMat,split);` now first Mat has x coordinates and second has y coordinates. But this is probably slower than manual solution =)

Comment: Oh dear. Slow just won't do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `cv::Mat` has a [constructor with a data pointer and a step](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-mat), you can make two as containers for the interleaved x and y components of each `Point2f` in the `vector`, which has contiguous data.

**Code**

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

int main(int argc,const char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> sides;
    sides.push_back(cv::Point2f(3, 4));
    sides.push_back(cv::Point2f(6, 8));
    sides.push_back(cv::Point2f(1, 1));

    cv::Mat xpts(sides.size(), 1, CV_32F, &sides[0].x, 2 * sizeof(float));
    cv::Mat ypts(sides.size(), 1, CV_32F, &sides[0].y, 2 * sizeof(float));

    std::cout << "x: " << xpts.t() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "y: " << ypts.t() << std::endl;

    cv::Mat magnitude, angle;
    cv::cartToPolar(xpts, ypts, magnitude, angle);

    std::cout << "\nmagnitude: " << magnitude.t();
    std::cout << "\nangle: " << angle.t() *180. / CV_PI << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The key is the step, `2 * sizeof(float)`.  The data will not be copied unless you `clone`.

**Output**

```
x: [3, 6, 1]
y: [4, 8, 1]

magnitude: [5, 10, 1.4142135]
angle: [53.136284, 53.136284, 44.990456]
```